# Converting event driven code to blocking code

Tags: java, concurrency, blocking

I have a class that calls an interface, like the below:

```
interface MessageReceiver{
  public void messageReceived(Message m);
}
```

However, because I am receiving messages from multiple sources that I need to synchronise I would instead like to have code that blocks on receiving messages. i.e. I would like to implement the following (blocking) interface, so my calling process can block on a new message coming in:

```
public Message getNextMessage();
```

However, my attempts so far end up getting bogged down with Thread synchronisation and locking issues... when really this *could* be done on the same Thread (concurrency is not required), but I am not sure how, without delving into assembler... and for that, java is probably not the easiest language to do this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would think very hard about doing this. Most software engineering changes go in the opposite direction, from blocking to event driven. I'm not convinced by your stated motivation.

Comment: (1) The event driving code is some horrible mess written by someone else.. that I would prefer not to touch if I can help it.  (2) Event driven might work, but I have some stuff already built and working that uses blocking and would need to re-write it to event driven, but that still doesn't solve this head-scratcher... ;-)

Comment: I don't see the big difference between your preferred way and having one single `MesageReceiver` and a synchronized `messageReceived()` to receive from multiple source.

Comment: @Adrian Shum The messages are all timestamped from each source, and I want to process them in chronological order.  As a result, I poll them all using a get method then choose whichever is the earliest.  I am not clear how I would do this with a single MessageReceiver.

Comment: Even you implement it like what the answer suggests, it still cannot work: it is possible that a "latter" message arrived first and then put into the queue and you polled it to process, and then an "earlier" message arrived, put in queue and you poll to process next.  If you are concerning on chronological order from individual source, then simply make your `messageReceived()` synchronized, and then use only one message receiver instance to do the processing.

Comment: or in short, if "processing using one properly-synchronized message receiver" is not going to work, having "a message receiver to act as a channel by putting them in blocking queue" is not going to work either, because it is essentially the same approach.

Comment: I have 3 sources where I am taking the first message from each source. Whichever is the earliest, I process the message and then get the next message from that source and repeat.   However, I suppose that for an event driven approach, I could have an ordered queue, and process up to the earliest timestamp of the 3 sources combined.  Note - because I am processing data from files which were recorded previously, the order of events being fired would be different from the timestamps on the messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create intermediate object with a blocking queue inside. Register it as a MessageReceiver.

```
class Channel implements MessageReceiver {
  BlockingQueue q=new ArrayBlockingQueue();

  public void messageReceived(Message m) {
     q.put(m);
  }

  public Message getNextMessage() {
    return q.take();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. Queues seem to be the solution to almost all concurrency issues.

Comment: This looks like it might do the trick.  Looking at what BlockingQueue does, it looks like what I was trying to do... unsuccessfully.